# Creating a function for a simple select statement?

Tags: sql-server

I'm writing an application and I'll be running the following query:

```
SELECT Job_name,EMP,Lastname,FirstName from employe E
inner join JOBS F ON F.CODE_JOB=  E.CODE_JOB
inner join EMPS S ON S.Code_str = E.CODE_STR
where USER_ID = X
```

Does it make sense to actually make a function for it and send the USER_ID as a parameter or should I just run the query in the application? I'm just looking to know what are the best practices here.

Answer (score 4):

You could write an inline table valued function, or use a view to encapsulate this code, but it would depend on what you hope to get out of it.

There's no performance gain by doing so. It can make the application query simpler, or obfuscate table names, but that's about it.

Obfuscating table names may provide an additional, though minimal layer of security. Any escalation of privileges could result in someone seeing the view definition and exposing the table names anyway.

Comment: Interesting. Obfuscating tables names is for protection against hackers? since you call the function, there is no way a hacker would know the tables name, correct?

Comment: @Hackawar Minimal protection, but yes.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give your thoughts about the comment I made above?

Comment: @Hackawar done -- let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: I appreciate it, that was helpful but I was referring to my comment I made to the other user (Kin) above since you recommended function while he said procedure.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to rerun the same code with different user_id then just create  a stored procedure and have user_id as parameter.

e.g.

```
Create procedure dbo.usp_GetEmpDetailsPerUser @user_id int
as 
 set nocount on
SELECT Job_name,EMP,Lastname,FirstName from employe E
inner join JOBS F ON F.CODE_JOB=  E.CODE_JOB
inner join EMPS S ON S.Code_str = E.CODE_STR
where USER_ID = @user_id 
option(recompile) -- do not cache the plan
```

Comment: I have read that I should use functions in my current case (SELECT STATEMENT). No? For what's its worth, the returned value will be always 1 row.

Comment: Yes, it is safer to use a parameterized function/proc because it's easier to sanitize the inputs and avoid injection attacks.